# @Id generated value in monogdb spring mvc

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to generate different id for my db but it keep generate 0 and delete the old record how can i generate id in this code knowing that i need the id to be int for front end angular service .

```
@Document(collection = "tasks")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Field(value = "task_id")
    private int id;

    @Field(value = "task_name")
    private String taskName;

    @Field(value = "task_description")
    private String taskDescription;

    @Field(value = "task_priority")
    private String taskPriority;

    @Field(value = "task_status")
    private String taskStatus;

    @Field(value = "task_archived")
    private int taskArchived = 0;

   //set and get

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found two ways to do it first one

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static int nextValue() {
        return counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    /*******************/

    @Id
    @Field(value = "task_id")
    private int id = nextValue();
```

second one i consider it a trick is to use current Date as an integer

```
private int id = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);
```

Comment: I think the best way is what i advised you to do. Have an incrementor and practice atomic incrementations on it. Assuming later multiple threads can play with this class. And the @Transient is for ignoring the field in persistence. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is two generate unique ID with one of method provided by Java

1. UUID ( Universal Unique ID)
2. SecureRandom and MessageDigest
3. UID
4. Atomic Integer increments (that is what you need)
5. And many other methods

Depending on your needs pick the most suitible one. Here is a method with AtomicInteger which solves your issue :

```
    @Document(collection = "tasks")
    public class Task {

        @Id
        @Field(value = "task_id")
        private int id;

        @Field(value = "task_name")
        private String taskName;

        @Field(value = "task_description")
        private String taskDescription;

        @Field(value = "task_priority")
        private String taskPriority;

        @Field(value = "task_status")
        private String taskStatus;

        @Field(value = "task_archived")
        private int taskArchived = 0;

        @Transient
        private AtomicInteger incrementor = new AtomicInteger(0);

        public Task() {
          id = incrementor.incrementAndGet(0);
        }
             //set and get
    }
```

Also you have to use `@Transient` to avoid the incrementor being persisted in the document store.

Comment: What is ai variable in id = ai.incrementAndGet(0);

Comment: @Transient not applicable for constructor

Comment: i solved it by a small trick
private int id = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);